# How to use CDN script with Shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify, liquid, cdn

I'm trying to use VueJs to develop a Shopify theme using Shopify Cli and Store 2.0.
I tried to install Vue using a CDN script in my theme.liquid

```
<script src="{{ 'vue.global.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
```

When I use it like that everything works fine and Vue Devtools detects VueJs but I get this error in theme check

```
Missing async or defer attribute on script tag
```

When I add async or defer attribute to my script tag Devtools doesn't detect VueJs anymore

[image]

How can I add Vuejs to Shopify without getting this error, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to ignore `theme.liquid` for ParserBlockingJavaScript check.

In your theme check config file (`.theme-check.yml`), find `ParserBlockingJavaScript` and add the file you want ignored. In your case:

```
ParserBlockingJavaScript:
  enabled: true
  ignore:
    - layout/theme.liquid
```

or you can choose to disable that check globally by changing enabled to false.

But another option for you to only disable the check for that specific code:

```
{% comment %}theme-check-disable ParserBlockingJavaScript{% endcomment %}
<script src="{{ 'vue.global.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
{% comment %}theme-check-enable ParserBlockingJavaScript{% endcomment %}
```

You can find more information here regarding the different checks: https://github.com/Shopify/theme-check